# Android: How to get installer file name programmatically?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

it is possible to get installer file name which is stored on /sdcard/
download/ ? I want to get from app, apk file name which installed it.
There is a easy way to do it especially with non-market app?

Comment: what do you mean by "installer file name" ? The name of the apk ? If yes, why do you want it ? Please add more details.

Comment: Yes I want to get name of apk which is stored on sd card. I created apk file and stored it on server, when someone want to download it, server generate file with unique name for example: "application00086.apk". The question is: how get this unique file name from my app which is after installation stored in directory: /data/app/ I found interesting method: getInstallerPackageName but this method return only installer package name and only for apps distributed on Android Market, I want to get installer file NAME and don't want distribute my app in Market.

Comment: @Wolfie: I faced with the same problem with you. Did you got solution for this. Thank you very much !

Comment: I have same problem. Any body found solution?

Answer (score 3):

The better way is definitely to include the version string in the manifest. This is really the only reliable (and professional) method. Android doesn't store the name of the file containing the APK anywhere, so there isn't a way that you can get it.

Theoretically you could probably build something using a `FileObserver`, that watched file creation in certain directories and every time a file was created with the extension `.apk` you could open the file, extract the manifest, find the package name of the APK and then store this along with the filename in some persistent storage. Then, when you need get the version information, you can look in the persisten storage to get the file name matching the package name you need.

Of course, this would only work if your app was installed on the device **before** the other APK files were downloaded/installed. This wouldn't work to find out the filename of your own application.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I am not sure what you mean by sdcard or download folder, but you could get apk path in system /data directory:

command line:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages | grep mk.trelloapp
package:mk.trelloapp
$ adb shell pm path mk.trelloapp
package:/data/app/mk.trelloapp-1/base.apk
```

or from you android application code: (simply run process)

```
        Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm path mk.trelloapp");

        exec.waitFor();

        InputStream inputStream = exec.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        String commandOutput = builder.toString();
```

Code above should simply give you String containing  "package:/data/app/mk.trelloapp-1/base.apk"

When you acquire path in /data directory, you might try to search for same (similar) file in other directories (assuming it was not deleted), since android package is copied to /data directory while instalation.

Comment: This isn't helpful. OP wants to be able to get the original filename of the APK file that was downloaded because the version number of his app is encoded as part of that filename. The APK path to `/data` doesn't include this information, as it only uses the package name.